# Error while executing Populate_Geometry_Columns() Postgis

Tags: mapinfo, postgis-2.0, postgresql

I loaded data into postgis using easy loader(MAPINFO). Now when I run

```
SELECT * FROM Populate_Geometry_Columns()
```

I get error :

> WARNING:  Could not convert '"SP_GEOMETRY"' in
>   'vectormaps."data_bnd"' to use typmod with srid 0, type:
>   MultiLineString  CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function
>   populate_geometry_columns(boolean) line 51 at assignment

1. How do i check this error?

Comment: Are you using MI Pro v12.0 or EasyLoader for v12? Not sure we support PostGIS 2.0 prior to v12.0. The problem could be that the table here is using a coordinate system that hasn't an EPSG-code.

Comment: @PeterHorsbøllMøller I am using mapinfo 11 and easyloader that came with it.

Comment: Officially we don't support PostGIS 2.0 before MapInfo Pro 12.0. Maybe that explains the problem? Could you try to download EasyLoader 12.0 and use that to upload the table to PostGIS? Get it here: http://www.pbinsight.com/support/product-downloads/item/easyloader-v12.0

Comment: @PeterHorsbøllMøller I will download it and try.

Comment: @PeterHorsbøllMøller is easy loader free? or do we require licence?

Comment: EasyLoader is free. I must however say that I'm not sure if it does require you to have the matching version of MI Pro.

Comment: @PeterHorsbøllMøller anyway i will use it :D